# Code in R to conditionally subtract columns in data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a data frame from a measurement where for each measurement a background is also measured:

```
 Wavelength   Background_1   1   Background_2   2   ...
 300          5              11  4              12  ...
 301          3              12  5              10  ...
 ...          ...            ... ...            ... ...
```

I want to subtract the appropriate "Background_xyz" column from the corresponding column (e.g. subtract "Background_1" from "1". It would then look like this:

```
 Wavelength   1_corrected   2_corrected   ...
 300          6             8             ...
 301          9             5             ...
 ...          ...           ...           ...
```

I can get this far no problem. The problem is, sometimes there are 3 measurements, so 3 columns with background and "real" data each, sometimes there are only 1 or 2 measurements. I am looking for a way to have R "correct" columns by subtracting the background independent of the number of columns to do so. I was thinking maybe an `if` function checking for the column names would to the trick but I am not experienced enough to figure out a way to do that yet.
Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the columns which have only numbers using `grep`, you can then get the corresponding `"Background"` columns and subtract.

```
cols <- grep('^\\d+$', names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- paste0(cols, '_corrected')
df[new_cols] <- df[cols] - df[paste0('Background_', cols)]
df[c("Wavelength", new_cols)]

#  Wavelength 1_corrected 2_corrected
#1        300           6           8
#2        301           9           5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Wavelength = 300:301, Background_1 = c(5L, 3L), 
`1` = 11:12, Background_2 = 4:5, `2` = c(12L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am just wondering, why you use "new_cols" because I don't see it being defined and I get an error when I try to use it like you suggest

Comment: @Nuramon Sorry, i forgot to include the line. Updated the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: I get a different error now:
Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Background_1`, `Background_2`, and `Background_3` don't exist.

Comment: @Nuramon Please adjust the answer based on your real data. Check the column names that you have in your data and the ones that you have shown. Do you really have columns with names as "1", "2" etc or are they named differently. If you are unable to adjust the answer according to your data then add your data using `dput(head(df))` instead of `.......` so that we can help.

Comment: I figured out the error (on my part), thank you for your help!